# I'm trying to import two rating scores from a website into google sheets. but I am unable to get it to work

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to import the PVE and PVP scores [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqFSK.png)

Website:

https://www.light.gg/db/items/4164201232/1000-yard-stare/

What ive tried:

=IMPORTXML("https://www.light.gg/db/items/4164201232/1000-yard-stare/","//div[@class=’col-xs-6’]")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
=transpose(importxml(A1,"//div[@class='col-xs-6']/span"))
```

Comment: thank you so much! do you happen to know offhand if I can have the data input via rows and not columns?

Comment: answer updated!